# Bootstrap 3.0.3 highlight label does not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason everytime I try the label does not highlight blue like its supposed to as I saw in this video-http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-w0qaYBDo0

Neither do the buttons look the same, my clear is flat and so is my submit it's not round or bulging out like for i.e when you click sign in on Twitter. Also when I try to space the Label it doesn't space instead it sort of went down and theres no separate space. Can anyone please help me? I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am on a PC btw if that changes anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what's going on without seeing any code.

By the sound of it, you may not have your bootstrap css included properly.

Try including this line in your head section to add the bootstrap css from a public hosted source, and remove your own line adding bootstrap.css in the  section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The paths you are are using to your bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js files are probably not correct. You will be getting a log in the browser console if this is the case.

How to access the console of your browser is different for each one, but a quick google search on how to open the console in your browser should tell you pretty quickly.

Best of luck.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more detail. Please try the new <link> code I put in, it seems the old one was no longer hosted or temporarily down.